# How do I highlight area in a map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, windows-phone-8, dictionary, bing-maps

I want to highlight area in a map, it can be any area (irregular shape). Any suggestions, how can I achieve this using
1. Windows Phone 8.1 map control
2. Any third party maps

I can do pushpins in map control, but I have to highlight area.

Help is much appreciated?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Quick internet search returns following results:

- http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/drawing-circles-windows-phone?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+zones/dotnet+%28.NET+Zone%29
- http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2014/02/drawing-translucent-shapes-and-lines-on.html

Please be more specific in your questions next time. If you are doing some research, try searching for problem in the internet before asking questions here. This site is for answering concrete questions for which you are unable to find solutions for.

Comment: Hi Thanks for giving out to me. I did search on internet and I did see these links. However, I think you might have mistaken while reading my question or perhaps I might not have explained clearly. I am looking for IRREGULAR SHAPE [any shape of city/cities, area(s)]. The links your have provided. first one is doing a circle (not a irregular shape) otherone is polygon, which is missing certain portion of cities.

Comment: But isn't any irregular shape just a polygon?

Comment: It is a polygon. but polygon in example is only 4 liner. What I am looking for is the shape of city (exact to its lines in map). In the previous version of our application, we had static maps with yellow shade spread on the city. we want to move from that to more advanced maps. Hence the requirement of shape going over city. And it should cover the full city.

Comment: By the definition, polygon can have any number of sides, not just 4. I mean, poly = many.

Comment: Yeah and if u read the original question, I did say irregular shape

Comment: So what is the problem then? What is your question?